# Paginate result of foreach loop with php

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, foreach, pagination

UPDATE***I am attempting to paginate the result of this foreach loop. This ALMOST works. Im able to get all of the information I need to paginate, but ALL results show on each page.  The record count is correct, the generated page numbers are correct.  All I'm missing is having the correct number of records display to each page. I understand I need to add the "LIMIT" portion to the sql but where?

UPDATE#2 - LIMIT was working, BUT, I found that the records displayed are treated as just 1 record because they reside in a list in 1 field.  So, I need to somehow explode the result into separate pieces for an accurate count. I hope that makes sense.

```
//$page is generated on another page and is working correctly

   $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM profile_tbl WHERE X_reg_id = '$var_reg_id'");

    while($field = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
        $list = $field['profile_choose_them'];
        $list_count = preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $list);
        $records_per_page = 3;  
        $item_count= count($list_count);
        $item_count_adj_total_records = ($row_count-1);
        $total_pages = ceil($item_count_adj_total_records/$records_per_page);
        $offset = (($page-1)*$records_per_page);

    }

        foreach(preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $list) as $id){    

                   $single = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM profile_tbl WHERE X_reg_id = '$id'");

                        while($display = mysqli_fetch_assoc($single)){

                            echo '<div><img src="'.$display["profile_pic_main"] .'"></div>';       

                        }

        }

for($page=1;$page<=$total_pages;$page++){
    echo '<a href="../../'.$var_return_ref.'?page='.$page.'">'.$page.'</a> ';
}
```

I tried this, but it does not display my items, only page numbers

```
$single = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM profile_tbl WHERE X_reg_id = '$id' LIMIT ($offset, $item_count_adj_total_records)");
```

Comment: You've searched SO for other questions like this right? What solutions have you already rejected?  Please edit your question to  give more details.

Comment: Yes, I have searched for DAYS...many many hours of trying different "solutions"  I don't even open this site without doing that.  All of my attempts failed or I wouldn't be here.  I think my question is striaght forward.  I need to paginate that code.  That's kind of it.

Comment: you are nesting three loop one inside the other. This is completely unclear. Why do you need this? Your code looks incredibly overcomplicated for what you need to do

Comment: Right, I agree, I don't know how to clean it up!

Answer (score 0):

Since you ask about `foreach` loop specifically, I am guessing that is the part you need to paginate. It seems to loop over set of multiple IDs.

The most brute force way to split such array into pages on pure PHP level would be to chunk it:

```php
$ids_array = preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $my_fields['profile_choose_them']);
$pages = array_chunk( $ids_array, 10 );

foreach( $pages[0] as $assign_id ) { // this would loop through first 10 items

}
```

`$pages` will contain original array split into arrays of 10 elements. So each entry in `$pages` could be treated as set of IDs for a single page.

Comment: Thank you Rarst.  That looks like it is helpful, but the problem I keep running into is WHERE or how to implement  this.  Do I replace the foreach(preg_split part with the $ids_array variable?  I don't know how the entire piece of code should look.

Comment: Well, I don't know how entire piece of code should look either. Your question says you already have the experience paginating arrays, you could look up existing approach in same code base and adjust to this.

Comment: The code I posted, is how it looks right now.  No differences, so I'm asking how to put your code into mine.  If i could implement my other pagination code (as I have been trying to do for 5 days, I would have done that.)  I am doing it wrong so I'm asking for the correct order of things.

Comment: I have edited a bit for how `foreach` would be adjusted. Note that this doesn't account for logic of processing different pages since your code doesn't have any inputs related to what current page would be.